# C Calculator help-- Can't get min and max values

Tags: c, if-statement

Every time I run it, min and max are the same numbers, and is sometimes wrong and I'm completely lost on why this is. It's a basic calculator based on user input. I'm guessing this is the main problem but if not I'll edit it with the rest of the code.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
  printf("Enter data item %d: ", i);
  scanf("%f", &data);

  sumx = sumx + data;
  sumx2 = sumx2 + (data*data);

}


mean = sumx / n;
var = 1.0/(n-1) * (sumx2 - (1.0/n)*sumx*sumx);
sd = sqrt(var);


if (data > max){
 max = data;
}
else if(data < min)
  min = data;
/* print the computed values */

printf("\n");
printf("mean = %f\n", mean);
printf(" variance = %f\n", var);
printf("std. dev. = %f\n\n", sd);
printf("The minimum number in the list is %d.\n", min);
printf("The maximum number in the list is %d.\n", max);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not initially setting max or min to anything. So, when you compare data to max or min, they'll contain "random" values. Also, you'll only ever set **either** min or max, not both with your above code.

Comment: You're only comparing min and max to the last data item entered -- you should compare data to min/max inside the for-loop.

Comment: The `data` value is evidently a `float`, whereas `min` and `max` are evidently `int`s. They should probably all be the same type.

Comment: min and max should be of type float, and should be initialized as min=FLT_MAX, and max=-FLT_MAX, respectively

Comment: You should fix your indentation and style to be more consistent, it will make your code easier for you to read.

Answer (score 1):

You did not show the initial setting of min and max to the default values.

```
float mymin = FLT_MAX;
float mymax = FLT_MIN;
```

you should also not use the if else if in order to make sure that the first time you start the loop you set the data.

Additionally, since you run the loop and complete it before you issue the test, you are only testing the values at the very end of the processing, which means that you never do check for min or max. The other type changes are also shown below.

```
int myfunc(int n)
{
  float mymin = FLT_MAX;
  float mymax = FLT_MIN;
  float sumx = 0.0;
  float sumx2 = 0.0;
  float data;
  float mean;
  float var;
  float sd;
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    printf("Enter data item %d: ", i);
    scanf("%f", &data);
    if (data > mymax){
      mymax = data;
    }
    if(data < mymin) {
      mymin = data;
    }
    sumx += data;
    sumx2 += (data*data);

  }
  mean = sumx / n;
  var = 1.0/(n-1) * (sumx2 - (1.0/n)*sumx*sumx);
  sd = sqrt(var);

  /* print the computed values */

  printf("\n");
  printf("mean = %f\n", mean);
  printf(" variance = %f\n", var);
  printf("std. dev. = %f\n\n", sd);
  printf("The minimum number in the list is %f.\n", mymin);
  printf("The maximum number in the list is %f.\n", mymax);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems are

1) while reading the data's you've to store it in arrays, but you're storing the data read each time in the same variable *data* , you've to use it as *data[i]*

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {

  printf("Enter data item %d: ", i);
  scanf("%f", &data[i]);
  sumx = sumx + data[i];
  sumx2 = sumx2 + (data[i]*data[i]);

}
```

2) For finding min and max values ,start with a refernce value and compare with the whole elemnts of array,where you're just comparing min&max values with one element only

```
int min,max;

max=data[1];
min=data[1];
for (i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
    if(data[i] > max)
        max=data[i];

    if(data[i] < min)
        min=data[i];
}
```

after this loop , you've the min and max values of array